# Contact Evaluation in Journey Builder - Application Level

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a simple yet hard to find answer regarding contact evaluation setting in JB.

When using an automation in order to inject contacts into journey there is a setting named Contact Evaluation. My question is whether this setting applies to all versions of the journey (similar to how Contact Entry setting works) or just the current version viewed/edited?

I did not find any mention regarding this in the official documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5

My main concern is if I set the setting as below:

[image: pic2]

Does it mean:

1. For the journey's first scheduled run - all data extension records will be evaluated?

OR

2. For the specific version's first scheduled run - all data extension records will be evaluated?

Thanks for the helpers,
Barak